# BeautifulSoup extract conditioned digit coloured by css

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I successfully get the data from this table from [THRIVEN](https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/stocks/view/7889) :
[image]

But as you can see, at the `Net%` column, those values negative/positive are determined by some **CSS** (which I believed, and I couldn't find them where they are located).

How can I extract those data and put them into my Excel as negative/positive numbers?
Below is my current code :

```
lwb = load_workbook(filename='THRIVEN.xlsx')
lws = lwb['THRI']

klseLink = 'https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/stocks/view/7889'
klseParser = BeautifulSoup(klseLink.text, 'html.parser')

currentQuarterReportTable = klseParser.find('table', {'class': 'financial_reports table table-hover table-sm table-theme'}).findAll('tr', limit=5)
currentQuarterReportSelectedRow = []

print("")
print("==================== CURRENT QUARTER REPORT =====================")
print("")

try:
    for currentQuarterReportRow in currentQuarterReportTable[1:]:
        navigatedCurrentQuarterReportColumn = [td.text.strip() for td in currentQuarterReportRow.findAll("td")]
    
        navigatedCurrentQuarterReportColumn.pop(0)
        navigatedCurrentQuarterReportColumn.pop(0)
        navigatedCurrentQuarterReportColumn.pop(0)
        navigatedCurrentQuarterReportColumn.pop(4)
        navigatedCurrentQuarterReportColumn.pop(6)
        currentQuarterReportSelectedRow.append(navigatedCurrentQuarterReportColumn)
    
    currentQuarterReportLimitedTable = pd.DataFrame(currentQuarterReportSelectedRow, columns=['Revenue', 'Profit/Loss', 'Quarter', 'Quarter Date', 'Announced Date', 'Net'])
    currentQuarterReportLimitedTable = currentQuarterReportLimitedTable.rename(index={0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4'})
    print(currentQuarterReportLimitedTable)

    i = 0
    for currentQuarterReportRow in currentQuarterReportTable[1:]:
        i += 1
        selectedColumn = [td.text.strip() for td in currentQuarterReportRow.findAll("td")]
        quarter = selectedColumn[5]
        quarterDate = selectedColumn[6]
        announcedDate = selectedColumn[8]
        revenue = (selectedColumn[3].replace("k", "")).replace(",", "")
        profitloss = (selectedColumn[4].replace("k", "")).replace(",", "")
        net = selectedColumn[9].replace("%", "")
    
        lws.cell(18 + int(i), 3).value = int(quarter)
        lws.cell(18 + int(i), 5).value = quarterDate
        lws.cell(18 + int(i), 7).value = announcedDate
        lws.cell(18 + int(i), 9).value = int(revenue)
        lws.cell(18 + int(i), 11).value = int(profitloss)
        lws.cell(18 + int(i), 13).value = float(net)

except IndexError:
    print("No Quarterly Report from KLScreener")
    
lwb.save('THRIVEN.xlsx')
```

Giving me :

[image]

Note that the `Revenue` and `Profit/Loss` colors are conditioned in Excel itself.

**EDIT :**

Finally I can achieve this by :

```
for currentQuarterReportRow in currentQuarterReportTable[1:]: #currentQuarterReportRow in currentQuarterReportTable[1:]:
    currentQuarterReportRow = currentQuarterReportRow.find_all('td')[-2]
    if currentQuarterReportRow.find('span', {'class':'btn-sm btn-danger'}):
        print(float(currentQuarterReportRow.get_text().replace('%', '')) * -1)
    else:
        print(float(currentQuarterReportRow.get_text().replace('%', '')))
```

Thanks to @HedgeHog suggesting the solutions! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `class` of the `button` to differentiate positive or negative value:

```
if net.select_one('.btn-danger'):
    print(float(net.get_text().replace('%',''))*-1)
else:
    print(float(net.get_text().replace('%','')))
```

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<tr class="table-alternate">
<td class="number">-1.20</td>
<td class="number">0.000</td>
<td class="number">0.3400</td>
<td class="number">34,780k</td>
<td class="number">-6,537k</td>
<td class="text-center">4</td>
<td><span style="white-space: nowrap">2020-12-31</span></td>
<td><span style="white-space: nowrap">31 Dec, 2020</span></td>
<td><span style="white-space: nowrap">2021-02-25</span></td>
<td class="number"><span class="btn-sm btn-danger">20%</span></td>
<td><a href="/v2/stocks/financial-report/7889/2020-12-31" target="_blank">View</a>                                </td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-alternate">
<td class="number">1.27</td>
<td class="number">0.000</td>
<td class="number">0.3500</td>
<td class="number">49,244k</td>
<td class="number">6,959k</td>
<td class="text-center">3</td>
<td><span style="white-space: nowrap">2020-09-30</span></td>
<td><span style="white-space: nowrap">31 Dec, 2020</span></td>
<td><span style="white-space: nowrap">2020-11-20</span></td>
<td class="number"><span class="btn-sm btn-success">35%</span></td>
<td><a href="/v2/stocks/financial-report/7889/2020-09-30" target="_blank">View</a>                                </td>
</tr>

'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

for currentQuarterReportRow in soup.find_all('tr'):
    net = currentQuarterReportRow.find_all('td')[-2]
    if net.select_one('.btn-danger'):
        print(float(net.get_text().replace('%',''))*-1)
    else:
        print(float(net.get_text().replace('%','')))
```

**Output**

```
-20.0
35.0
```

Comment: may I know, why .find_all('td')[-2]? What is the [-2] meaning?

Comment: It is the equivalent to your position picking with `[9]` only the other way around - sorry, my habit   ---   You can also do it like `net = currentQuarterReportRow.find_all('td')[9]`

Comment: I change it into:  for currentQuarterReportRow in currentQuarterReportTable[1:]: #currentQuarterReportRow in currentQuarterReportTable[1:]:
        currentQuarterReportRow = currentQuarterReportRow.find_all('span')[-1]
        if currentQuarterReportRow.select_one('btn-sm btn-danger'):
            print(float(currentQuarterReportRow.get_text().replace('%', '')) * -1)
            print("It should be NEGATIVE!")
        else:
            print(float(currentQuarterReportRow.get_text().replace('%', '')))
            print("It should be POSITIVE!")
        print(currentQuarterReportRow)

Comment: but all of them return POSITIVE, so it means the code still cannot recognize the CSS :(

Comment: FINALLY!     for currentQuarterReportRow in currentQuarterReportTable[1:]: #currentQuarterReportRow in currentQuarterReportTable[1:]:
        currentQuarterReportRow = currentQuarterReportRow.find_all('td')[-2]
        if currentQuarterReportRow.find('span', {'class':'btn-sm btn-danger'}):
            print(float(currentQuarterReportRow.get_text().replace('%', '')) * -1)
        else:
            print(float(currentQuarterReportRow.get_text().replace('%', '')))

Comment: Thanks a lot @HedgeHog !